# Is "reserved" an adjective or verb in this example?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, parts-of-speech, past-participles, participles

I need an answer about this sentence please:

> We had a **reserved** seat.

*Reserved* in this sentence is a verb. I read that in a morphology book. 
My question is: how does this become a verb?  I thought it was an adjective.

Comment: Here, *reserved* is a [participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle): "a form of a verb that is used in a sentence to modify a noun or noun phrase, and thus plays a role similar to that of an adjective or adverb."

Comment: Right. So, it's an adjective **and** it's a verb. It's a verb form (there are two kinds of participle in English -- active, ending in _-ing_, and perfect, ending in _-ed/-en_) that gets used as an adjective. _Reserved_ is the perfect participle of the verb _reserve_, and it can modify _seat_, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Reserved is an adjective in this context.

From ODO:

[Reserved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reserved) - *adjective* - kept specially for a particular purpose or person:

> a reserved seat

Answer (score -1):

> - *"We had a* ***reserved*** *seat."*
>
> ***Reserved*** in this sentence is a verb. I read that in a morphology book.
>
> My question is: how does this become a verb? I thought it was an adjective.

Here, it seems that the word "reserved" can be a past-participle verb form that is functioning as an attributive modifier of the head noun "seat". That is, it can be a **"verb"**. And here in your example, it has a passive interpretation (which they most often do) -- *the seat was reserved by somebody for us*.

Many different types of category (adjective, adjective phrase, noun, verb, etc.) can function as an attributive modifier in noun phrase structure.

For instance, **adjective phrase**:

- a ***long*** letter
- this ***latest*** problem
- some ***very irate*** customers

or **determinative phrase**:

- another ***two*** candidates
- the ***more than thirty*** candidates

or **nominal**:

- a ***brick*** wall
- ***high octane*** petrol
- a ***United States*** warship

or **verb phrase**:

- the ***condemned*** man
- a ***sleeping*** child
- a ***recently discovered*** fossil

We know that the word "reserved" can be a verb form because it can be used as a typical verb: *"We reserved a seat at the restaurant", "A seat was already reserved at the restaurant by her parents".* (As to the possibility of it also being a past-participle adjective, that's a different issue.)

Note that the above examples were borrowed from the 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction To English Grammar*, page 95.